# Extracting individual steps from incrememental data

Tags: r

I have some incremental data, let's call it `v`.  Clearly, v<sub>i</sub> = v<sub>i-1</sub> + x for i > 1.  What I want to extract from the data is x so that I can plot it.

How can I do that with R?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [diff](http://stat.ethz.ch/R-manual/R-devel/library/base/html/diff.html) function, e.g.:

```
a <- c(1, 2, 3, 3, 5.5)
x <- diff(a)

> x
# [1] 1.0 1.0 0.0 2.5

plot(x,typ='l')
```

[image]